# Extras in one activity are not in the next activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to start a new activity onItemClick in a list view.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ItemListActivity.this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            try {
                intent.putExtra(MEMORY_ID, result.getJSONObject(position).getInt("id"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            intent.putExtra(LATITUDE, currentLocation.getLatitude());
            intent.putExtra(LONGITUDE, currentLocation.getLongitude());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

When it gets down to startActivity(intent), I can see that the correct values are in the intent through the debugger. However, when I do getIntent() in ItemDetailActivity, that intent has no values. The mMap is null.

The code for accessing extras is

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
// Create a new HttpClient and build GET request
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://128.61.107.111:56788/memories/view_specific/" +
    intent.getStringExtra(ItemListActivity.MEMORY_ID) +
    "?latitude=" + intent.getStringExtra(ItemListActivity.LATITUDE) + 
    "&longitude=" + intent.getStringExtra(ItemListActivity.LONGITUDE));
```

What's going on here? Am I not grabbing the correct intent? How are my values being lost?

Comment: What happens when you `getExtras`? Might be judt a problem of the debugger

Comment: Show your called activity onCreate function... did you mean getIntent().getExtras()?

Comment: Also show code from ItemDetailActivity where you grab the extras.

Comment: getExtras just returns null when I do getString(). I've updated the question with the code where I grab the extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Int and Double types, not String.
try using intent.getIntExtra and intnet.getDoubleExtra or just do intent.getExtras() in debug mode and watch the values inside.